# Helicon ISAPI rewrite

Tags: javascript, iis-6, http-headers, isapi-rewrite

I'd like to add cache and expires headers for all my .js files because I'm not able to do it on my server. I'm using IIS. How might I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying you don't have access to administer the server?  If you can access the IIS management console, you can set these headers directly through the UI:

http://www.webpaths.com/archives/software/microsoft/iis/2009/02/05/how-to-add-an-expires-header-in-iis.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Helicon Ape [mod_headers module](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/mod_headers.htm). But note that it works only for IIS7 and higher.